# Auto-generated names to be Alphabets instead of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
empIdn  date        new
517     2019-05-02  [12:00:12, 12:32:05, 05:18:57, 05:23:02]
```

I wanted to split the values in column `new` to individual columns.
something like this

```
empIdn  date        time_0      time_1      time_2      time_3
517     2019-05-02  12:00:12    12:32:05    05:18:57    05:23:02
```

I was able to do this with

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df3.new.values.tolist(), df.index).add_prefix('time_'))
df.drop('new', axis=1, inplace = True)
```

The questions I have:

1. Is there a way to make the automatically generated names to be alphabets (A,B,C..) instead of numbers?
2. Can the line to drop column `new` be integrated in the first line itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename` for convert integers to uppercase alphabets and for remove `new` use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
import string
d = dict(enumerate(list(string.ascii_uppercase)))
#print (d)

df = df3.join(pd.DataFrame(df3.pop('new').values.tolist(), 
                           index=df3.index)
         .rename(columns=d)
         .add_prefix('time_'))

print (df)
empIdn        date    time_A    time_B    time_C    time_D
0     517  2019-05-02  12:00:12  12:32:05  05:18:57  05:23:02
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. I hope this will help.

If you are trying to generate the columns names instead of time_0 to time_A, then you are not generating it, you are passing `df.index` which is RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1) eg. (0,1,2,3) and then adding suffix to make it `time_`.

Now your question is to generate column name as time_A, time_B, time_C and time_D.

It can done using below code.

`pd.DataFrame(data.new.values.tolist(), columns=['A','B','C','D']).add_prefix('time_')`

For your second question, you can use drop statement with join as below:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(data.new.values.tolist(), columns=['A','B','C','D']).add_prefix('time_')).drop('new', axis=1)
```

Ouput will be as below :

```
  empIdn       date       time_A    time_B  time_C  time_D
0   517    2019-05-02   12:00:12    12:32:05    05:18:57    05:23:02
```